# Substring a sum

Tags: java, substring

I want to substring my string but don't know how.

What I want is this:

```
10
10
*
```

(this depends on the user input)

What I currently have as output is this:

```
10
10
```

So I am missing the *, i am testing this with a teststring and it looks like this:

```
String test= "10;*;10";
System.out.println(test.substring(test.lastIndexOf(";") + 1));
System.out.println(test.substring(0, test.indexOf(";")));
```

How do I fix that the String test is getting several substrings and get the output 10 - * - 10?

Comment: Any reason to not use [String.split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))?  `test.split(";")`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're just missing to account for the middle *
Try: `System.out.println(test.substring(test.indexOf(";"), test.lastIndexOf(";")));`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) function from the string class.

```
String test = "10;*;10";
String splits[] = test.split(";");

for (String split : splits) {
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

Comment: I'd either do `List<String> splits = new ArrayList<>(test.split(";"))` just 'cause arrays are fairly rubbish. Not necessary in this case, obviously. Or alternatively, ditch the temporary variable and do `for(String token : test.split(";")) {`

Comment: `String[] splits = ...` is more convential in java, the other way was for C style usage. Just a comment.

Comment: a temporary variable could make the OP understand clearly

Comment: Nice that works pretty good, thanks. But I am sending the test to the server and the server substrings the items he got. But when i receive everything in the array I cant do this (I guess): 10 * 10 = 100

Comment: you will have to convert the strings to integers to perform some calculations on them.

Comment: I know but how do I take them from the split?